# covering map from spheres to projective spaces and the associated vector bundle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, vector-bundles, kt.k-theory-and-homology, characteristic-classes

Let $S^n$ be the $n$-sphere and consider a $2$-sheeted covering
$$
S^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}P^n.
$$
We have an associated vector bundle
$$
\xi: \mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow S^n\times_{\mathbb{Z}/2}\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n
$$
where the nontrivial element of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by reversing the order of coordinates.

**Question:** What is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that the Whitney sum
$
\xi^{\oplus k}
$
is stable equivalent to a trivial bundle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Theorem 7.4 of J. F. Adams, Vector fields on spheres, Ann. of Math. 75 (1962), 603–632
says that $$\tilde{KO}({\mathbb R} P^n)=\mathbb Z\,/\,2^{\phi(n)},$$ generated by $\xi-1$, where $\phi(n)$ is the number of integers $s$ such that $0 < s\le n$ and $s$ is congruent to 0,1, 2 or 4 modulo 8, and $\xi$ is the canonical line bundle over $\mathbb RP^n$ given as $S^n\times_{\mathbb Z/2} \mathbb R\to \mathbb RP^n$, where $\mathbb Z/2$ acts on $ \mathbb R$ by multiplication with $-1$.

Since your vector bundle is the direct sum of $\xi$ and the trivial 1-dimensional bundle, the answer to your question is $k=2^{\phi(n)}$.